# What is the best way to parse JSON files and create Model objects and then map them to the Core Data database?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following instance method in my class, where "jsonObj" is a Dictionary:

```
func getSurvey(countryId: String, languageId: String, surveyId: String, userId: String, completionHandler: ((ICSurvey!, NSError!) -> Void)?)
    {
        ICWebServicesManager.downloadSurvey("", languageId: "", surveyId: "", userId: "") {

            (jsonObj, error) -> Void in

            if completionHandler != nil
            {
                if error != nil
                {
                    completionHandler!(nil, error)
                }
                else
                {
                    let surveyJSONObject = jsonObj

                    let survey = ICSurvey()

                    if let surveyIdObj = surveyJSONObject["id"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
                    {
                        self.dateFormatter!.dateFormat = "y-M-d'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"

                        survey.id = ICSurveyId(
                            surveyId : surveyIdObj["survey_id"]!,
                            countryId : surveyIdObj["country_id"]!,
                            languageId : surveyIdObj["language_id"]!
                        )

                        survey.uri = surveyJSONObject["uri"] as? String
                        survey.title = surveyJSONObject["title"] as? String
                        survey.startDate = self.dateFormatter!.dateFromString(surveyJSONObject["start_date"] as! String)
                        survey.endDate = self.dateFormatter!.dateFromString(surveyJSONObject["end_date"] as! String)
                        survey.type = surveyJSONObject["type"] as? String

                        survey.questionGroups = Array()

                        if let questionGroupsJSONObjects = surveyJSONObject["question_groups"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                        {
                            for questionGroupObj in questionGroupsJSONObjects
                            {
                                let questionGroup = ICQuestionGroup()

                                questionGroup.questions = Array()

                                questionGroup.text = questionGroupObj["text"] as? String

                                if let questionsArrayObj = questionGroupObj["questions"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                                {
                                    for questionObj in questionsArrayObj
                                    {
                                        var question = ICQuestion()

                                        if let questionIdObj = questionObj["id"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
                                        {
                                            question.id = ICQuestionId(
                                                questionId : questionIdObj["question_id"]!,
                                                languageId : questionIdObj["language_id"]!
                                            )

                                            question.type = questionObj["type"] as? String

                                            var requiredString = questionObj["required"]
                                                as? String

                                            question.required = (requiredString == "True" ? true : false)                                                
                                            question.setValue(questionObj["text"] as? String, forKey: "text")

                                            if let questionResponseObj = questionObj["response"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                            {
                                                question.response = ICResponse(
                                                    type : questionResponseObj["type"] as! String,
                                                    value : questionResponseObj["value"] as! Int,
                                                    clientTimestamp : self.dateFormatter!.dateFromString(questionResponseObj["client_timestamp"] as! String)!
                                                )
                                            }

                                            if let questionResponseObj = questionObj["options"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                                            {
                                                question.options = questionResponseObj
                                            }
                                        }

                                        questionGroup.questions!.append(question)
                                    }
                                }

                                survey.questionGroups!.append(questionGroup)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    self.currentSurvey = survey

                    completionHandler!(self.currentSurvey, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After doing some code review with my mentor, he told me everything is pretty good, except I need to "abstract out hard wired properties". My understanding is that he does not want to have code that looks like this:

```
survey.startDate = self.dateFormatter!.dateFromString(surveyJSONObject["start_date"] as! String)
```

, because "start_date" for instance is hard-coded.

Instead, I should find what objects the JSON file represent and map that data correspondingly. While I agree to that to some extent, as the app code will not need many changes if it do it that way, it seem to be an overhead for me because I need to map everything to Core Data, and if a property changes, many things may change or crash.

My question is: What is the best way to parse JSON files and create Model objects and then map them to the Core Data database?

How do we have to "abstract out hard wired properties"?

If anyone has more experience with Web Services integration, please give me some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try JSONJoy https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy I have used in my project and its really good.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SwiftyJSON on previous projects but now I've converted everything to Swift 1.2 (if let,) syntax and I honestly like it more since it feels like I have more flexibility and it alleviates 3rd party framework dependency.

As far as your "hard-coded" values, simply utilize optionals for testing. For instance, the following line requires a value to be present. Test for that value prior to unwrapping it. His fear is that if that object doesn't exist for whatever reason your program will crash.  (This isn't tested but you should get the idea)

```
surveyId : surveyIdObj["survey_id"]!,

if let surveyId   = surveyIdObj["survey_id"] as? String,
   let countryId  = surveyIdObj["country_id"] as? String,
   let languageId = surveyIdObj["language_id"] as? String {
       survey.id = ICSurveyId(
             // You could also test here for each and add the values to your survey object
             surveyId : surveyIdObj["survey_id"]!,
             countryId : surveyIdObj["country_id"]!,
             languageId : surveyIdObj["language_id"]!
       )
 }
```

Personally I prefer just creating a new NSManagedObject and assigning the values directly.

```
var survey = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Survey", inManagedObjectContext: self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext!) as! Survey
// Then just assign the values to the object using dot notation
survey.surveyId = surveyIdObj["survey_id"]!
// and so on  
// Then save the context
self.managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
```

Comment: In your code will the whole if statement fail if for instance only `survey_id` will give an error

Comment: The chained if let will require all values to exist then continue. Depending on if this fits your model you'd test each or all as one.